# Page loading takes forever

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple method:

```
public async Task<List<Steam>> Get()
{
    ObjectResult result = new Models.ObjectResult();
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var Object = await client.GetAsync("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001/");
        if (Object != null)
        {
            JObject steamobject = JObject.Parse(Object.ToString());
            var item = steamobject.SelectToken("applist").SelectToken("apps");
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectResult>(item.ToString());
        }

    }
    return result.MyList;
}
```

in my Index.cshtml :

```
        SteamGet getter = new SteamGet();
        List<Steam> Games = getter.Get().Result;
        foreach (var item in Games)
        {
           <li>
               @item.Name
           </li>
        }
```

This makes me wait forever!

Answer (score 11):

This is a deadlock situation.

You're using `.Result` which blocks the current thread and waits for response - 
while in the `async` method , after finished — it tries to get back to that thread but 
 that thread is  already blocked ( by your .`Result`).

You should `async`/`await` all the way  (or use `ConfigureAwait(false)`)

Comment: I understand the answer but how can i manage to await all the way ? i cannot await in the razor

Comment: My answer is in the general form for async deadlock problem. You should not have any thread waiting logic in any form in the View.You should do all that logic *in the controller*.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405(v=vs.110).aspx) method, but i think it will fault, because `SynchronizationContext` in asp.net not so easy.

Not bad practice is:

Controller

```
public async Task<List<Steam>> Get()
{
    ObjectResult result = new Models.ObjectResult();
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var Object = await client.GetAsync("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001/");
        if (Object != null)
        {
            JObject steamobject = JObject.Parse(Object.ToString());
            var item = steamobject.SelectToken("applist").SelectToken("apps");
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectResult>(item.ToString());
        }

    }

    SteamGet getter = new SteamGet();
    ViewBag.Games = await getter.Get();
    return result.MyList;
  }
```

View:

```
foreach (var item in (Viewag.Games as List<Steam>))
        {
           <li>
               @item.Name
           </li>
        }
```